# black screen of death when write to BIOS Flash ROM

Tags: x86-16, bios

I'm trying to write a program that is installed onto BIOS, but when I tried to run it, I got a black screen of death and my computer crashed.

What is wrong in my code below?

```
cli
mov ax,0B108h
xor bx,bx
mov di,0090h
int 1Ah
push cx
or cl,00110000b
mov ax,0B10Bh
xor bx,bx
int 1Ah

mov ax,0F000h
mov es,ax
xor di,di
mov cx,0010h
mov al,11h
cld
rep stosb

pop cx
mov ax,0B10Bh
xor bx,bx
mov di,0090h
int 1Ah
sti
wbinvd
```

Comment: How did you run your program in bios flash ram?

Comment: `mov ax,0F000h
mov es,ax
xor di,di
mov cx,0010h
mov al,11h
cld
rep stosb`

Comment: @brunosalvador All that does is write a sequence of `0x11`s from `F000:0000` to `F000:0010`. What's the point of that?